Integrating a 2nd ODE that contain a first derivative squared term
The 2nd ODE that I want to solve numerically is:
xddot = ( 0.5 * rho * A * Cl * ( xdot^2 + vy^2) ) / m
ODE
The vy term is a sinusoidal function and does not need to be solved numerically.
I have transfromed it into a coupled 1st ODE by:
xdot = vx
vxdot = ( 0.5 * rho * A * Cl * (vx^2 + vy^2) ) / m
The fact that the xdot term is squared in the ODE makes the solution very unstable. What are possible solutions to mitigate this?
Attached is the output of the ODE that I am getting.
Output

As soon as vx gets sufficiently large, your equation is essentially close to v'=C*v^2which is a well-known example of an exploding solution, of a dnamical blow-up, of a (simple) pole at finite time. There is nothing to repair, it's just the mathematics of it. You should also have gotten an appropriate error message, of values getting too big or the step size getting too small.
